# How does the Go SDK for Azure create a virtual machine without a service principal?

Tags: azure, go

[This sample code from the Go SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples/tree/main/services/quickstarts/deploy-vm) creates a virtual machine by deploying an ARM template.  It requires that you include the clientId and clientSecret from a service principal.

[This sample code from the Go SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples/tree/main/sdk/resourcemanager/compute/create_vm) creates a virtual machine using the Go SDK for Azure.  It requires a subscription ID, but no service principal (client id, client secret) is required.  It does not create a service principal automatically either.

I would think that a service principal would be required to create a VM, but the GO SDK example is able to create a VM without specifying a service principal.  What a I missing about service principals and virtual machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the [NewDefaultAzureCredential](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples/blob/main/sdk/resourcemanager/compute/create_vm/main.go#L161), this class retrieves the auth info from the environment (e.g. azure CLI, environment vars) - [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authentication?tabs=bash)

```
func connectionAzure() (azcore.TokenCredential, error) {
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return cred, nil
}
```

[image]

Comment: In my case it uses Option 3 in the docs (az login).